# Unable to setup DD4T 1.31 project

Tags: dd4t, java, spring

I have followed the steps from https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/31_Quickstart

at step number 6

> **Add projects to Eclipse**
>
> In your Eclipse, add the folders under `\java` as Eclipse projects. You will see that both projects have lots of build errors due to lacking jarfiles.

Here while adding Importing project in Eclipse as general project, when I select `java` as root directory then Eclipse is not able to find any project. I can add a Maven project but still, the example site is not added up. Is there any detailed documentation available for setting up DD4T with Java and Tomcat.

Additionally in steps it written to copy `tridion` dll, is this required as this is a Java application?

One more question: Where can I look for a quick start guide for  DD4T 2.0 with Java?

Comment: Have you referenced the SDL Content Delivery JAR files?

Comment: yes.. And will it make difference for loading project in eclips. I can see there is no .pom file in example website.